# Google Chrome for Android <select> element doesn't select any option

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, select, drop-down-menu

I've a select element on my single page web app. The app has responsive design to work on mobile devices. Below is the link for development version.

http://mapcodexpublish.com/mcxwebdev/

Theselect element works well on all browsers but chrome for mobile. On  chrome for android, when I thouch it shows the option list, but when select an option, it doesnt change at all. I've tried to alert something on change event but it wasn't fired.

I tired on real devices, but here is screenshots from an emulator. That's exact same.

[image: state 1]

[image: state 2]

[image: state 3]

Is there any one had similar problem or any idea to solve this wierd problem ?

Comment: I'm seeing a similar kind of weird problem where I have a <select> that doesn't get updated for SOME of the options of the select.  Seems related to the processing being done in the onChange event handler.  Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 5):

The super hacky fix that seemed to work for me was to trigger a blur event on the select when it triggers a change. Something like:

```
$('select').change(function(){
  if (/Android/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    $(this).blur();
  }
});
```

Really not proud of this "fix", but it works.