# Bootstrap dropdowns not working on Android

Tags: android, html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap

### The problem

If you go to https://oorkle.com/browse from a desktop browser and look at the left-hand side you will see a filter/sidebar that uses Bootstrap dropdowns, and you'll see that they work (they drop down):

[image]

If you narrow the view enough, some jQuery will move those dropdowns into the secondary top navbar, but they will still work (they'll drop down):

[image]

---

Now, if you try these same things while loading the page from Android or iOS (iPhone or iPad), you'll see that the dropdowns no longer work:

[image]

[image]

---

### The HTML

If you [diff the HTML of the desktop version and the HTML of the Android/iOS version](https://www.diffchecker.com/0GeIoczr), you'll see only minor CSS differences:

[image]
[image]
[image]

---

If you [diff the live HTML (with modifications from JavaScript)](https://www.diffchecker.com/GnsiVjIS), the only real difference from the diff above you'll see is that a `mobile` class has been added to each selector:

[image]

---

### What I've tried

- If you try the `Responsive` option in Chrome Devtools, which uses an Android User-Agent string, the dropdowns will not work, regardless of how wide the page is when it loads.
- I have tried configuring the server to serve *identical* HTML for the desktop and Android/iOS versions of the page, and I see the same behavior: the desktop dropdowns work, and the Android/iOS dropdowns don't work.
- I've tried using Chrome Devtools to remove the `mobile` class from the selectors and that doesn't seem to have any effect (the dropdowns still don't appear).
- The website is using Boostrap v3.0.3.  If I replace the v3.0.3 `bootstrap.js` file with the latest v4.1.3 `bootstrap.js` file it still doesn't work, but I'm not sure if it ever would be expected to or if the CSS classes may have changed.
- I have tried this on an actual Android device to confirm that it's really happening and not just a Chrome Devtools bug.
- I tried updating the website from Bootstrap v3.0.3 to the latest v3, v3.3.7, but it seems to have had no effect.

---

### My guess at what's happening

It seems to me that the user agent string is being used by Bootstrap in some way which is causing the dropdown to not work.

---

### Related issues I've found online

- I Googled and found [this Bootstrap documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744437/html-select-box-not-showing-drop-down-arrow-on-android-version-4-0-when-set-with) but while they seem somewhat related (in that they involve bugs with the user agent string), they don't seem to solve my problem.
- [Google Chrome for Android <select> element doesn't select any option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21110776/google-chrome-for-android-select-element-doesnt-select-any-option)
- This person seems to be encountering the same issue: [Simple html select not working on android chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312436/simple-html-select-not-working-on-android-chrome)
- [2016.09.21 - Google Chrome Help Forum - Select option not working on new update chrome](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Q4Rt6d0C4Qo)

  > It is likely that your library (or your code) handles the first click by simulating a second click programmatically on the HTML select when the user clicks on the outer element.
  >
  > A programmatic/scripted mouseevent is considered "non-trusted" and the default event will not be handled. Aka, the select will not be expanded and the user must click again.
  >
  > If you are using a library that provides an entire widget (some element + an HTML select), try updating your library to the latest version to see if they are taking another approach (besides programmatically sending a mouseevent to the HTML select).

### Updates

- I had a colleague test on a real iOS device and he reported that the dropdowns were working properly, but that on iOS the user isn't shown a dropdown window that looks like the one on desktop:
  [image]

Comment: Did you already fix it? It's working for me, I am replicating exactly what you did.

Comment: @TomDickson No, it's still not working for me when I use Chrome Devtools to simulate an Android / iOS device.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache in chrome? Have you also tried another browser?

Comment: @TomDickson I have Devtools set up to not use the cache.  At your suggestion I just tried it in Firefox Developer Edition and I still don't see the dropdowns, however because my colleague showed me that on iOS the select values are shown differently (they appear in an iOS-specific UI at the bottom of the phone's screen), I suspect I may need to use an emulator to see if using a different browser makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is a result of the selects using the [FormStone Selecter plugin](https://github.com/FormstoneClassic/Selecter) (v2.2.3), which presumably uses jQuery to handle the clicks, which [it seems Android now treats as a security threat and does not allow](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/Q4Rt6d0C4Qo).

To solve the problem I had my Web.py (Python web framework) template file look at the user agent string, and if "android" appeared, it would set the selects' class to "form-control" (a Bootstrap class), thus letting Bootstrap style the selects, and if "android" was *not* in the user agent string it would use the FormStone Selecter plugin as usual.

So, to clarify: despite my thinking that the selects were using Bootstrap and that Bootstrap was not working, it turns out that the selects were *not* using Bootstrap, and that Bootstrap v3.0.3 selects *do* work on Android.